# Redirect a subdomain to a different login page

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have a domain with a subdomain set up like the following in my vhost.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/mysite/webapps/ROOT/
    ProxyPassMatch / ajp://localhost:8084
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mysite.com 
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/mysite/webapps/ROOT/
    Redirect /index.jsp /index2.jsp
    ProxyPassMatch / ajp://localhost:8084
</VirtualHost>
```

The main site loads `index.jsp` but I would like the subdomain to load up a different JSP file (`index2.jsp`).

I've tried using Redirect but it just goes to `index.jsp` on the subdomain.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use different directories as `DocumentRoot`?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

The following is wrong due to the presence of `ProxyPassMatch`.

<strike>It's been ages since I last configured an Apache VirtualHost, but I think</strike>

```
DirectoryIndex index2.jsp
```

is what you're looking for.

So, the complete config would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mysite.com 
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/mysite/webapps/ROOT/

    # Serve index2.jsp as index file
    DirectoryIndex index2.jsp

    ProxyPassMatch / ajp://localhost:8084
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**

I didn't look hard enough, looks like the `ProxyPassMatch` directive overrides a lots of other commands:

```
As the ProxyPassMatch directive is evaluated as the very beginning of each request:
  -AddType (for MultiView) or DirectoryIndex directives are not usable
  -right management per directory is not available
  -each Alias directive needs another proxy rule
```

The problem is that your `index2.jsp` will *never* be served by Apache as the server's already matched the ProxyPass /, and so it's already been passed to `ajp://localhost:8084`.

You should then manage serving `index.jsp` or `index2.jsp` on `ajp://localhost:8084`.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse - I've tried this out and the subdomain still goes to index.php unfortunately

Comment: @Duckula Looks like I was wrong and the problem lies in `ProxyPassMatch`. I've updated my answer.